# Carousel redirects to 404notFound route

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, web

I've got a problem with the carousel i'm using currently for my website.
I tried to find someone who has got the same problem but i didn't find.

I've got some routes to redirect the user to some different pages and on the main page, i've got a carousel.

The problem is when I click on the left or right arrow of the carousel, it redirects me to the 404notFound i defined with the appRoutes.
I think it comes from the fact that the module tries to check if the route (here the anchor of the carousel) exists in the appRoutes and, because it doesn't, redirects me to my error page.

Here are my routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'customers', component: CustomersComponent},
  {path: 'pricing', component: PricingComponent},
  {path: 'teaminapp', component: TeaminappComponent},
  {path: 'eventapp', component: EventappComponent},
  {path: 'species', component: SpeciesComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  {path: 'notFound', component: FourohfourComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/notFound'}
];
```

My carousel I took from W3Schools:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="../../../assets/test.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Team In'App</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Offrez un espace privilégié et interactif à vos équipes, vos membres avec une application personnalisée, flexible et évolutive.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../../../assets/test2.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Event'App</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Dopez vos événements avec une application personnalisée, flexible et évolutive.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../../../assets/test3.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Solutions sur mesure</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, autem.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm ready to give you more of my code if you need.

I hope you will can help me .

Thanks !

Comment: it comes because you are using href attribute.which is redirecting some other page

Comment: so should I use routerLink instead of href ? so:

 <a class="right carousel-control" routerLink="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">

Comment: you can use routerLink but it seems you dont have myCarousel path in you routes

Comment: thanks for your answers,

what should I write in my routes to make my carousel work so ??
because a appRoute need a path and a component am i right ?

Comment: if you want to use carousel you can use ngBootstrap so that no need to use jquery

Comment: i was using ngBootstrap but there isn't transition between the slides and I looked for adding CSS style to this carousel but it looks impossible... i think i'm gonna use it anyway, i only have problems with the others one..

Comment: i suggest you to check this documentation https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

Comment: i'm gonna try this and i come back here if this is not working for me ! 
thank you

Comment: okay you are welcome

Comment: okay so i checked the link you sent me, i used the command "npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" to install bootstrap then i did the import in the module.ts
i copied & pasted the code of the first carousel on the link and the result is:
3 pictures, one after the other, with all the overlapping quotes at the bottom
my IDE also tells me that the ngb-carousel tag doesn't exist even though I installed it just before

i'm sorry if i'm doing some idiot mistakes

Comment: did you check your package.json

Comment: i just checked my packagejson and got "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" so i think it is well downloaded but i can't find where's the problem

Comment: can you stop and restart again and check

Comment: i restarted then i used ng serve again but the problem is present
to resume I:

added NgbModule.forRoot() to my imports
imported { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; in the module.ts too

and copied paste the html file from the example
did i forget something or it is supposed to be ok ?
i have no error during the compilation & no error in the console, just my IDE telling me that ngb-carousel doesn't exists so i'm lost

Comment: ya it's okay no problem

Comment: so i can't find where's the problem i don't know what i did wrong.. 
i will try to do another post to have more answers maybe but thanks for your patience !